# Suppose a box A is contained in a box B. Is the total volume of the k-faces of A at most the total volume of the total k-faces of B?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, discrete-geometry, polytopes, convex-geometry

This question inspired by question 2 from [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/solutions.pdf).

Say we have two $n$-dimensional boxes (not necessarily axis-aligned, otherwise the problem is trivial) $A$ and $B$, with $A$ contained in $B$.  Choose $1\le k\le n$.  Is the total volume of the $k$-faces of $A$ at most the total volume of the $k$-faces of $B$?  What if, instead of just boxes, we allow $A$ and $B$ to be general convex polytopes?  (Or $A$ convex and $B$ non-convex, but I'm not really clear on how non-convex polytopes may be defined, so maybe let's ignore that.)

The case $k=n$ is trivial as that's just the volume.

The case $k=n-1$... well, I'm not very familiar with convex geometry, but I *think* there might be some general theorem that if a convex body $A$ is contained in a convex body $B$, then the surface volume of $A$ is at most the surface volume of $B$, right?  Or no?  I'm hoping that's true.  Well, assuming it's true, it'll handle $k=n-1$.  (If it is true, a reference would be appreciated!)

The link above shows how to handle $k=1$ in the box case (specifically $k=1$ and $n=3$, but the proof generalizes to higher $n$), and actually I think it might generalize to convex polytopes in general, but I haven't fully checked.  Unfortunately, as best I can tell, this proof doesn't seem to generalize to higher $k$.

The case $k=0$ is trivially true for the box case and trivially false for the more general case, which is why I've excluded it!

So what about other cases?  Like the smallest case not covered by the above (assuming the above are all correct) is $k=2$ and $n=4$.  Is it true for boxes?  For convex polyhedra more generally?  Does anybody know about this?

Thank you all!

Comment: It's surely not true if you allow $A$ and $B$ to be arbitrary (different) convex polytopes. Imagine putting a long thin rectangular prism inside a long thin triangular prism. The former has 4 long edges instead of 3, so the sum of edge lengths is greater.

Comment: Oh, yeah, duh -- it's also easy to see from putting an $a$-gon inside a $b$-gon for $a>b$, and then taking a product with a hypercube.  OK, so that part's obviously false.  Hm -- maybe the proper generalization is if $A$ and $B$ are combinatorially equivalent (since stewbasic has handled the case where they're both parallelograms)?

Comment: I think that isn't enough either; you could pull the same trick with two triangular prisms. eg let $A$ be the convex hull of $\{(\pm1,\pm1,-L),(0,\pm1,L)\}$ and $B$ the convex hull of $\{(-1,\pm3,\pm L),(2,0,\pm L)\}$ where $L$ is large.

Comment: Huh, indeed so!  Guess I won't be asking that after all.  Interesting, certainly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true for any $k$ when $A$ and $B$ are $n$-dimensional parallelograms.

To see this, we need a description of the volume of $k$-dimensional parallelograms in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\{e_i\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$, so the wedge product $\wedge^k\mathbb R^n$ has a basis
$$
  \{e_{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e_{i_k}\mid 1\leq i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_k\leq n\}.
$$
There is a unique norm on $\wedge^k\mathbb R^n$ such that the above basis is orthonormal. Given vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in\mathbb R^n$, the volume of the parallelogram spanned by these vectors is
$$
  V(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\|x_1\wedge\ldots\wedge x_k\|_2.
$$
(We can take this as a definition, but to see that it makes sense, check that it is invariant under a matrix rotating in the plane $\mathrm{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$, and that it reduces to the determinant when all the $x_i$ are in $\mathrm{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$).

Now consider the $n$-dimensional parallelograms
$$
  A=\{a+t_1x_1+\ldots+t_nx_n\mid t_i\in[0,1]\},
$$
$$
  B=\{b+t_1y_1+\ldots+t_ny_n\mid t_i\in[0,1]\}.
$$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be the matrices whose columns are $x_i$ and $y_i$ respectively. We may suppose $Y$ is invertible (otherwise expand $B$ a bit and take the limit). Let $Z=Y^{-1}X$, so
$$
  x_i=\sum_j y_jz_{ji}.
$$
Fix $l$. Let $I=\{i\mid z_{li}>0\}$ and $I'=\{i\mid z_{li}\leq0\}$. Note that
$$
  a+\sum_{i\in I}x_i=a+\sum_jy_j\sum_{i\in I}z_{ji}\in B,
$$
$$
  a+\sum_{i\in I'}x_i=a+\sum_jy_j\sum_{i\in I'}z_{ji}\in B.
$$
Looking at the coefficient of $y_l$, we see that
$$
  1\geq\sum_{i\in I}z_{li}-\sum_{i\in I'}z_{li}=\sum_i|z_{li}|.
$$
This holds for each $l$. Now consider a $k$-dimensional face of $A$ spanned by $x_i$ for $i\in I$. The volume of this face is
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \|\wedge_{i\in I}x_i\|_2
    &=&\left\|\wedge_{i\in I}\left(\sum_j y_jz_{ji}\right)\right\|_2\\
    &=&\left\|\sum_J\wedge_{j\in J}y_j\det(Z_{JI})\right\|_2\\
    &\leq&\sum_J\|\wedge_{j\in J}y_j\|_2|\det(Z_{JI})|
\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the sum is over sets of indices $J$ of size $k$, and $Z_{JI}$ denotes the submatrix of $Z$ with rows from $J$ and columns from $I$. For fixed $J=\{j_1,\ldots,j_k\}$, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_I|\det(Z_{JI})|
    &\leq&\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}|z_{j_1i_1}\ldots z_{j_ki_k}|\\
    &=&\prod_{j\in J}\sum_i|z_{ji}|\\
    &\leq&1.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Therefore
$$
  \sum_I\|\wedge_{i\in I}x_i\|_2\leq\sum_J\|\wedge_{j\in J}y_j\|_2
$$
as required.

---

The statement is also true for $k=n-1$ when $A$ and $B$ are any convex polytopes; here is a sketch. Let $A_l$ denote the union of $l$-faces of $A$, and similarly for $B$. Given $x\in A_{n-1}\setminus A_{n-2}$, the ray from $x$ normal to the face containing $x$ intersects $B_{n-1}$ at a unique point $\phi(x)$. The resulting map
$$
  \phi:A_{n-1}\setminus A_{n-2}\to B_{n-1}
$$
is injective since $A$ is convex. Moreover if $\phi(x)\notin B_{n-2}$ then $\phi$ is linear and volume-increasing on some neighborhood of $x$. Since $A_{n-2}$ and $\phi^{-1}(B_{n-2})$ are of dimension $\leq n-2$, excluding these won't affect $(n-1)$-dimensional volume. Therefore
$$
  V(A_{n-1})=V(\phi^{-1}(B_{n-1}\setminus B_{n-2}))
    \leq V(B_{n-1}\setminus B_{n-2})=V(B_{n-1}).
$$

Comment: Oh, this is great!  Do you know if the "surface volume" statement is true without requriring polytopes btw?  I guess you can just make a continuous version of the above argument, maybe?  Also, it seems like your proof for parallelipipeds in parallelipipeds should generalize to simplicies in simplices as well.  I guess the generalization to ask about is "A in B, A and B combinatorially equivalent" -- I'll ask that as a separate question, I guess.

Comment: It seems like the surface volume argument should work for convex regions if the surface is nice enough (maybe piecewise $C^1$?) but I didn't carefully check. You can construct a tetrahedron example just like the triangular prism one, so simplices are also out.

Comment: Oh, good point!  For posterity, here's the vertices I used to do it: $A$ has vertices at $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,4L/5)$, and $(1/5,1/5,4L/5)$, while $B$ has vertices at $(0,0,0)$, $(2,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$, and $(0,0,L)$.

Comment: On top of that -- so it seems like the general trick is just having more edges inside running in the long dimension. So you could do it with polyhedra combinatorially equivalent to cubes, as well; it's only *specifically* parallelipipeds that work, it seems. Specifically, take the outside cube stretched from a vertex to an opposite vertex; this has 6 half-long edges so, effectively 3 long edges. Then put a box inside with 4 long edges. I think I'll skip working out a detailed example.

Comment: As for surface volume: Oh yeah, I forgot to think about differentiability requirements; I was sort of implicitly assuming differentiability, oops. Convex implies continuous on an open set, and I'm pretty sure that should apply here, but differentiable is another matter.  On the real line convex functions are pretty close to differentiable, but I don't know about close enough, and I am a little doubtful that sort of argument will work in more than one dimension.  This is why I was hoping somebody who really knows convex geometry would show up!

Comment: Oh, maybe it can be made to work, via the "subgradient" and "subdifferential".  Well -- not going to worry about it...